# How to display thumbnail in BREAD browse mode with Voyager Laravel Admin

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, voyager

I have a model with name : Category, which has a field is "image_url" (suppose that it's a big photo). How do I only show thumbnail image in BREAD browse mode of Category? 
Thank you!

Comment: I'm after something similar: the field references PART of a URL, and I'd like the Browse page to display the image by prefixing the domain/path etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up overriding the default Voyager bread view for the one table, as per https://docs.laravelvoyager.com/customization/overriding-files#overriding-bread-views
.. which says for version 1.1:

> You can override any of the BREAD views for a single BREAD by creating
>   a new folder in resources/views/vendor/voyager/slug-name where
>   slug-name is the slug that you have assigned for that table. There are
>   4 files that you can override:
>
> - browse.blade.php
> - edit-add.blade.php
> - read.blade.php
> - order.blade.php
>
> Alternatively you can override the views for all BREADs by creating
>   any of the above files under resources/views/vendor/voyager/bread

.. I just needed to override the 'browse' view. I also created a custom formfield as per https://docs.laravelvoyager.com/customization/adding-custom-formfields - the code for which just returned an `<img>` element with the src url correctly formatted.

Finally, in the custom 'browse' view, I added logic to check for the new formfield and returned code to display the image.

Would be SO good if there was another 'Optional Details' field in the BREAD editor for formatting the display in the browse page.

Anyway, hope that helps and I hope someone can point me in the direction of a more straightforward way of doing this ..

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It's really good answer. Currently, I think make a custom form field is the best solution. I'm hope in the future, voyager will support more configuration for BREAD display too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to override the template to show the image(s) in browse mode.

In the field settings, just add "show_as_images":true, and it will show the images in browse mode.

According to documents: https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/bread/introduction-1